# What does the notation $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ mean?

Tags: reference-request, notation, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I have tried looking at my sheaves notes but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's one of Serre's [twisting sheafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction#The_twisting_sheaf_of_Serre). In particular, it is the [hyperplane bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle#Hyperplane_bundle) of $\Bbb{P}^n$.

Comment: I'm far from being an expert, but I think I recall that line bundles on projective spaces are classified by integers (Chern class). So this would be the generator of the Picard group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For details a reference is the book of Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry", page 116. If $S$ is a graded ring, then a graded $S$-module $M$ gives a sheaf $\tilde{M}$ on $Proj(S)$. On the basic open, $\tilde{M}(D(f)) \cong \tilde{M_f}$.

Now, it's only pure algebra.

There is a general construction with $S$ a graded ring, and $M$ a graded $S-$module. We can define the "twisted module" $M(k)$ as $M$ with modified grading : $M(k)_n = M_{n+k}$.

Now, you can define $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1) = \tilde{S(1)}$.

For more details about the sheaves $\mathcal O(n)$, you can take a look this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112926/global-sections-of-mathcalo-1-and-mathcalo1-understanding-structu).